# Possible to have Dirac AND Majorana mass?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, mass, representation-theory, dirac-equation, majorana-fermions

Supposing you have a lagrangian consisting of $(1/2,0)\oplus (0,1/2)$ representation.

Writing in terms of Weyl fermions, the following terms are possible:

$$-\frac{m_1}{2} (\psi_R^T \epsilon \psi_R - \psi_R^\dagger \epsilon \psi_R^*)$$
$$-\frac{m_2}{2} (\psi_L^T \epsilon \psi_L - \psi_L^\dagger \epsilon \psi_L^*)$$
$$-m_3(\psi_R^\dagger \psi_L + \psi _L^\dagger \psi_R)$$

where $\epsilon = -i \sigma_y$.

Is there anything preventing all three terms from being present at once? Sure, if you have the Majorana constraint $$\psi_r =-\epsilon \psi_L^*$$ then actually all three terms are equal. But I don't see why one must always have this constraint... that constraint seems to be just a choice that one could investigate if one wishes.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105587/little-confusion-with-see-saw-mechanism) and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101114/neutrinos-and-anti-neutrinos-in-the-standard-model?rq=1). The [seesaw mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seesaw_mechanism)   *requires* all terms.

Comment: Salutary [discussion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/66817/66086).